# How do I get my controller in scope after JavaScript 1.2.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope

I've been following an Angular.js tutorial, however it is a bit old and this is not compatible after version 1.2.5

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="HelloController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>




</html>
```

**js file**

```
var MainController = function($scope)
{
  $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
}
```

how do I do this in 1.4.3 ? thanks

Comment: In your html you are referencing `HelloController` instead of `MainController `

Answer (score 0):

In your html you mentioning **HelloController** instead of **MainController**

Comment: sorry, even if they have the same name it doesnt work, i tried with some other code i found here with no success

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **controller** and add it to an **angular module**.

Be careful, `angular.module()` provide getter and setter syntax :

- getter : `angular.module('myModuleName')`
- setter : `angular.module('myModuleName', [])`

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  $scope.name = 'john';

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>

    Hello {{name}}

  </body>
```

[**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFs51MFu0ShiRfXRC1va?p=preview)